# Find elements equal to a value in a json file

Tags: javascript, json

I have a json file like this:

```
{
    id1: ["text1" , "content1" ],
    id2: ["text2" , "content2" ],
    id3: ["text3" , "content3" ]
}

var number =2;
```

How can I find property of json with id number equal to "number" and retrieve its 2 element "text2" and "content2".

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean something like this?

```
var number = 2;
console.log(json['id'+number]);
```

Its probably [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/dynamically-access-object-property)